# Set position of faces to act outward in every directions, not just one vector

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need my split faces to be duplicated outward of my icosphere in every direction to which each mesh is facing, not everything in just one direction as it is currently.

I've had this problem in many other situations. I know there is a solution but forgot what it is. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: did u try putting normal into extrude mesh -> offset?

Comment: Yes. Didn't work

Comment: I don't get it. The faces are being extruded along their normals.. but that's not what you want?

Comment: EXtrude is one thing but I need the duplication outwards. The visual I m looking for is not a succession of those spheres, but one sphere with its  faces duplicated outwards in all directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to move the duplicated faces along their normals.

If I am correct, you can achieve this as follows:

[image]

Here, after duplication, I first capture the normals of the faces.

Then I use the *Duplicate Index* value as the basis for scaling this direction vector and move the individual points along these direction.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>